# Getting TypeError when trying to log messages in discord

Tags: python-3.x, logging, discord, discord.py

Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def logsave(ctx, amount = None, logName = None):
    #Checks if user input an amount, either a number or "all".
    if amount == None:
        desc = f'**Specify an amount**'
        errorEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f'**Log**', description = desc, colour = discord.Color.from_rgb(36, 227, 170))
        await ctx.send(embed = errorEmbed)
        return

    #Checks if user input a name for the log.
    if logName == None:
        desc = f'**Specify a name.**'
        errorEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f'**Log**', description = desc, colour = discord.Color.from_rgb(36, 227, 170))
        logMsg = await ctx.send(embed = errorEmbed)
        return

    #Checks if user input "all"
    if amount.lower() == 'all':
        isAll = True
    else:
        isAll = False

    #Gets message history
    channel = ctx.channel
    if isAll:
        desc = f'**Started Logging**'
        startEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f'**Log**', description = desc, colour = discord.Color.from_rgb(36, 227, 170))
        logMsg = await ctx.send(embed = startEmbed)
        messages = await channel.history(limit = None, oldest_first = True).flatten()
    else:
        messages = await channel.history(limit = int(amount), oldest_first = True).flatten()

    #Loads previous logs for editing
    logsFile = open(f'{currentDirectory}\Saved\logs.json', 'r+')
    logsJson = json.load(logsFile)

    #Creates new message log in JSON
    logCount = logsJson[messages][-1]["count"] + 1
    newLog = {
        "name": logName,
        "creator": ctx.author,
        "msgs": [],
        "count": logCount
    }
    logsJson["messageLogs"].append(newLog)

    #Stars logging the messages, I'm pretty sure this is where my error is coming from.
    for msg in messages:
        msgAuthor = msg.author
        if msgAuthor.bot:
            return
        print("done")
        msgContent = msg.content
        msgAttachments = msg.attachments
        msgCreated = msg.created_at
        msgWrite = f'\n{msgAuthor} [{msgCreated}]\n{msgContent}'
        newMessage = {
            "id": msg.id,
            "authorname": str(msgAuthor),
            "authorid": msgAuthor.id,
            "content": msgWrite,
            "published": msgCreated,
            "attachments": msgAttachments
        }
        logsJson["messageLogs"][logCount]["msgs"].append(newMessage)

    #Edits previous log.
    json.dump(logsJson, logsFile)
    logsFile.close()

    #Ends
    logMsg.delete()
    desc = f'**Finished Logging**'
    endEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f'**Log**', description = desc, colour = discord.Color.from_rgb(36, 227, 170))
    await ctx.send(embed = endEmbed)
```

This is the code for a command that stores messages in a JSON. The problem is that whenever I run this command in discord I get this error:

```
<discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x000001BB444DC370> Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I can't seem to figure out what's gone wrong. I've put comments in the code of the command to explain what each part does. I haven't yet figured out if the rest of the code is right so if there's more than one error, feel free to address that as well, right now though I'm just looking for the solution for the particular error above.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**
you probably meant to do `logsJson["messageLogs"][-1]["count"] + 1`

**More detail:**
When you try to lookup a dictionary with a list value, you get `unhashable type: 'list'` because dictionaries are just hash tables. You appear to do this here:

```py
logCount = logsJson[messages][-1]["count"] + 1
```

and you declared `messages` above this as:

```py
messages = await channel.history(limit = None, oldest_first = True).flatten()
```

which returns a list of all the messages. So Python can't hash this list and throws the above error. I am guessing you meant to put `"messageLogs"` in quotes `""` as strings are valid keys for a dictionary (they are hashable).

**Reproducible example:**

```py
x = [1,2,3]
y = {"hello": "world"}
print(y[x])
```

gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`